# Eclipse 3.4.2 - very tender

Tags: eclipse

When I select a folder in the Eclipse Project Explorer, the 'explosion' often will cause a file to 'moved' out of its current folder - sometimes even to another project - causing errors in the re-compilation (thankfully).

Does anyone have a solution to this 'tenderness'? (If relevant, I am using Ganymede under Eclipse 3.4.2 with the Android Plugin.)

Comment: Could you please describe this "explosion" a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked On Eclipse Ganymede in Linux
I think there is problem  with your Setting of editor

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that the OP is accidentally doing a drag-and-drop and moving files.  I couldn't see a simple way to turn off drag-and-drop in the preferences editor.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen C. I suspect you're correct. [I'm using an expensive but old Logitech Trackball via a USB port on a laptop. Maybe this is the 'last straw' in the argument for an upgrade to my development environment!]

Answer (score 0):

I work with Eclipse a lot, I've used Ganymede for over a year under Linux and sometimes Windows, and neither I nor any of my colleagues have ever seen such a problem.

My guess is that there are problems between your mouse and display drivers, i.e. you are inadvertently clicking on other things when you are meaning only to explode. Can you try opening folded branches by selecting the item and hitting the `+` key rather than clicking in the GUI?